# How to leave a blank field in table in sqlplus?

Tags: sqlplus

In sql, if some fiels are to be left blank while inserting the values in the table, how shall we do it?
For eg. For name field, i want to insert 'First Name' & 'Last Name' but not 'Middle Name'.
But the field is already present by default in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you simply need to execute an INSERT sentence, without using the columns (fields) you don't want to inform.

As an example, if you have three columns and don't want to inform column2 use

INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column3)
VALUES (value1,value3);

instead of

INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3);

Hope it helps!

Comment: If the field has a default value you don't want... then you can insert a NULL value or an empty string ('')

Comment: Hello, yes u understood me correctly, but if there are more than 20 columns in the table, then I need to write Column name of every column except the ones I dont need?

Comment: Can you plz then mark my answer as OK closing your question? Thank you.